# How to display notifications across browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, notifications, microsoft-edge

I am trying to create a web site that displays notifications when some event happens. I have checked [the MDN page for Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/notification) and I have written an example that works in Firefox Developer Edition 58.0b7 but has a strange behavior in Edge 40.15063.674.0 and Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (in Windows 10).

Here is a minimum complete verifiable example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  function notify(str) {
  if(!("Notification" in window) || Notification.permission === "deneided") {
    return alert(str);
  }
  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    return new Notification("TITLE", {body: str});
  }
  Notification.requestPermission().then(perm => {
    console.log("request result", perm);
    console.log("Notification.permission", Notification.permission);
    if (perm === "granted") {
      return new Notification("TITLE", {body: str});
    }
  });
}

notify("test");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Save that code in a file in your computer and open it with a browser.

- In Firefox, if you grant permissions whenever asked it works and a notification is displayed.
- In Chrome, if you grant permissions you can see in the console that the permission request returned `"granted"` but `Notification.permission` is still "default" and the notification is not displayed. Running `notify` again results in another dialog asking for permissions to display notifications.
- In Edge, after granting permissions, `Notification.permission` is `granted`, but atempting to create a new notification results in an `UnknownError`.

Why is the code working in Firefox but not in Edge or Chrome? How can I make it work at least in Chrome (and hopefully in Edge)?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the example they provide in the [MDN notification API Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) under "Alternate example: run on page load" you can achieve showing notifications with less overhead.

try the code below with local files(the snippet here will deny Notification attempts)

In Chrome you will see the `Notification.permission` variable updated after refreshing the page.

```js
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});

document.querySelector('#notifyButton').addEventListener('click', showNotification)

function showNotification(){
 console.log('Clicked!!')
 var options = {
     body: 'this is the body!'
 }
 var n = new Notification('this is the title', options);
}
```

```html
<input id="notifyButton" type="button" name="notify" value="click for notification">
```

Comment: Using your code in chrome results in the same outcome as my code. The notification is not shown, and `Notification.permission` is still `"default"` even after reloading the page.